# How to detect your IP/name using gethostbyname()

Tags: c, sockets, ip

is there a way to get the IP number from `gethostname()`?

We are randomly generating IP addresses for the computers in the lab we are in. We use `gethostbyname(<random ip>)` to get the IP of a computer.

What we want to do essentially is compare the ip that we get from gethostbyname() with what we get from gethostname().

We tried:

```
struct hostent* host;
char temp[MAX_LEN];
gethostname(temp, MAX_LEN);

host = gethostbyname(<random ip address>)

if(host->h_name == temp) printf("They are the same\n");
```

> The problem is, is that host->h_name is **'172.125.45.1'** (i made that
>   up) and temp is **'u-my_comp'**

so we cant compare the strings cause one gives us the name of the computer (u-my_comp), and the other gives the ip...

Is there anyway to make these functions return the same type of value?

we have tried doing something like

```
gethostname(temp, 24)
temp_host = gethostbyname(temp)
```

in hopes that now we could compare temp_host->h_name with host->h_name...but yeah, that didnt work either.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: What OS are you on? Look at this post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738552(v=vs.85).aspx, try the `h_addr_list`

Comment: ubuntu. I have tried playing with the h_addr_list

Comment: What did you try with h_addr_list ?

Comment: quite a few things. this has been the only thing that provided anything legible: ipbuf = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)hostentry->h_addr_list[0])); ...but it always returns 127.0.1.1 (shouldnt it be 127.0.0.1 anyways?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gethostbyname()` is for converting a hostname into a socket address.  If the "hostname" you supply is a dotted-quad IPv4 address, that will be all you get in the `h_name` parameter of the result.

To convert a socket address back into a name what you want is the companion function `gethostbyaddr()` - except that you don't, because both `gethostbyname()` and `gethostbyaddr()` are deprecated.  Instead, you should be using `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()`.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    char host[1024];
    int gni_err;

    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = 0;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    gni_err = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa, host, sizeof host, NULL, 0, NI_NAMEREQD | NI_NOFQDN);

    if (gni_err == 0) {
        printf("host is: %s\n", host);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error looking up host: %s\n", gai_strerror(gni_err));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call:

```
myhost = gethostbyname(temp);
```

(having allocated myhost) then you will have two hostent structures you will compare - you will have the IP address lists for both the target query host and the current host (not just the hostname for the current host).